# powershell "if" needs to set two variables on match

Tags: powershell

I need to set two variables in a script...

The first is obviously $vmcluster - What's the proper syntax to set another variable if my "if" matches?

```
if ($vmname -like "LouPr*") {$vmcluster = "Production"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a script-block.... just use another line, or seperate with `;` .

```
if ($vmname -like "LouPr*") { 
    $vmcluster = "Production"
    $secondvar = "secondvalue"
    }
```

or

```
if ($vmname -like "LouPr*") { $vmcluster = "Production"; $secondvar = "secondvalue" }
```